# React Native JS frame drop when dispatching redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm developing an application using React Native + Redux and Redux Thunk. In one of actions, a large json data is fetched from our server and then dispatched to the store. When the dispatch happens, the JS thread frame rate drops from 60fps to 0 or 1 fps and so all touchables and buttons become not responsive and it's impossible to navigate through the app for a couple of seconds until the dispatch concludes and everything become normal again.

We've already made sure that only the components that needs this reducer data are re-rendering but the problem persists.

The data we are downloading is a json similar to a Map that may have hundreds or thousands of values.

Is there any way I can make React Native and Redux deal with this kind of data without dropping frames

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem. I have the same. If the state is too big then the js tread frame dropped.

Answer (score 0):

> "[...], there's nothing inherently slow or inefficient about how Redux is implemented. In fact, React Redux in particular is heavily optimized to cut down on unnecessary re-renders [...]"

Shouldn't be a problem for [react-redux](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance). Try to optimize your overall component structure:

1. Implement shouldComponentUpdate()-Method or [PureComponents](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) to get away from [pointless rerenders](https://blog.logrocket.com/make-react-fast-again-part-3-highlighting-component-updates-6119e45e6833). You could also consider designing a [normalized redux state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape).
2. Split components in many individual pieces before connecting to the store.
3. Avoid overfetching and optimize lazy loading. You won't be able to display those data all at once.

[This repository](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#redux-performance) contains all articles treating the subject of 'Performance & Redux'. It's worth a visit ;)